# electric potential energy symbol in Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation

In my introductory physics class, $V$ is the symbol for electric potential (joules per coulomb) and $U$ is the symbol for electric potential energy (joules).

Since the Schrodinger equation is the sum of Kinetic and Potential energies in the system, $V(r)$ must represent $U$... if so, is there any particular reason why $V(r)$ is used as opposed to $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of notation. In fact, in my Mechanics course, I use $V$ instead of $U$.

I think that introductory courses don't use $V$ as $U$ to prevent confusion between potential energy and electric potential.

It's like using $T$ or $K$ as the kinetic energy.

And note that the potential in the Schrodinger's equation can be of any type, not only electrical.

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me that the potential can be of different types after posting my question... in the case of a harmonic oscillator, the potential energy is not electric potential energy, but spring potential energy (is that right)?  Thanks for adding some more detail, jinawee, your answer definitely makes sense.